# Как сделать проверку даты в Django

Tags: python, django, дата, datetime

`

```
class MakeStatus(models.Model):
    pass


class Card(models.Model):
    serial_num = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    number_card = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.ForeignKey('MakeStatus', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.ForeignKey('MakeStatus', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

`

Нужно засунуть проверку в Makestatus, которая будет проверять истек ли срок годности в переменной end_date, и если не истек status='Срок годности не истек', а иначе status='Срок годности истек'. Как реализовать данный функционал?

Comment: Как вы хотите реализовать это через ForeignKey? Ведь нужно лишь установить срок годности конкретным значением поля IntegerField.

Comment: Далее проверять больше ли значение этого поля чем разница текущей даты и даты создания

Comment: через админку. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: @bolt_py я не совсем понимаю как это сделать( я новичок )

Comment: А зачем вообще хранить статус в виде отдельного поля в базе? Если у вас есть чёткое условие (сравнение с текущей датой) — может, просто сделать status вычисляемым свойством через какой-нибудь @property и не хранить ничего?

Comment: @andreymal а как это сделать? Я просто не совсем представляю как

Comment: С помощью моделей вы определяете в каком виде вы хотите хранить объекты данных, задаёте им структуру. Для того что вы хотите сделать не нужно создавать отдельный класс модели, какие данные вы собираетесь там хранить? Ваша цель -- узнать истёк ли срок годности данного продукта. У вас есть два поля модели, всё что вам нужно это проверять значения этих полей.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно ссылаться на отдельный экземпляр модели. Удалите вашу модель `MakeStatus` и переопределите поля модели `Card` следующим образом:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    serial_num = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    number_card = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Для того чтобы узнать истёк ли срок годности товара, достаточно создать представление, которое сравнивает разницу текущей даты со значением поля `created_at`:

```
from path_to_your_models.py_file import Card
from dateutil import parser

def compare(request, cid):
    is_alive = True
    template = 'your_template'
    card = Card.objects.get(id=cid)
    time = parser.parse(card.created_at)
    if (datetime.now() - time).days > card:
       is_alive = False
    return render(request, template, {'is_alive': is_alive})
```

`cid` это ключ уникальный ключ по которому мы обращаемся к экземпляру модели.

Не уверен что написал всё в точности правильно, но надеюсь что смог передать идею

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал так:

```
class Card(models.Model):
serial_num = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
number_card = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
end_date = models.DateTimeField()
amount = models.IntegerField()
status = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Годен ли продукт')

def is_status(self):
    if end_date <= datetime.today():
         self.status = False
         self.save()
         return 'Продукт просрочен!'
    else: 
         return 'Продукт годен!
```

При этом важно отметить что перезапись статуса будет осуществлена только при вызове функции, поэтому если вы хотите чтобы статус вашей модели ежедневно обновлялся необходимо подумать о способе её вызова. Самый простой способ вызывать в представлении, так вам всегда будет показана актуальная информация.